# Load a webpage from a site with an expired domain

Tags: wordpress, url, ftp, filezilla

I had a portfolio URL that expired about a year ago, and there's a page from that portfolio I'd like to load/view. How can I do it? I used FileZila as my FTP client and all the assets from that page are sitting in there, I just don't understand what to do with them now that the URL is gone. Can anyone help with this issue?

This could also help - my new portfolio is run on a Wordpress-based CMS called Semplice.

Comment: Where have you hosted that expired website? shared hosting or VPS? does it have cpanel or smth. like that?

Comment: it was hosted by Namecheap, and I believe it has a cpanel

Comment: how do you access to that FTP? With IP address? Can you tell that IP and the name of expired domain?

Comment: @Elvin85 I accessed it via FileZilla, and I made any changes to the site through there. The expired domain is www.gelf.me

Comment: What is its hostname in ftp?

Comment: Please move your question to [su] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @Elvin85 How do I find the hostname information?

Comment: If you login via Filezille. You can see it there with "Host:" prefix. There are 3 parameters in Filezilla, which you are using for login. hostname, login, password.

Comment: i think the hostname is gelf.me?

Comment: @Elvin85 i was able to find a pure html version of the page via web.archive.org, but still no luck in getting the fully designed/coded page itself.

Comment: if the domain is expired, it can't be active hostname of your FTP.

Comment: @Elvin85 so what can i do?